# I want Section 1 and chapter one the same page. otherwise the section on the new page

Tags: titlesec, ifthenelse

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\ifthenelse{\value{section}=1\OR \value{section}=0}
{\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
    \let\bkdsection\section
    \renewcommand*\section{\bkdsection}}
{\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
    \let\bkdsection\section
    \renewcommand*\section{\newpage\bkdsection}
}
```

Comment: Please post a full example, showing what is (not) working for you.